# How to improve browse of a big Word table in VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I happen to have a Word table with 1,300 rows and 4 columns. This table contains a list of documents with their main characteristics.
Then I want to upload the content of this table in an array to have a maximum performance of some filtering functions.
My problem is that the upload duration grows exponentially with the size of the Word table : for 300 rows, takes a couple of seconds, for 600 rows, make it 15 seconds, for 1200 rows, it's more than 60 seconds.
I have tested several ways of browsing my table, for instance:

```
Dim My_Table as Table
Dim My_array(1 to 1300, 1 to 4) as string
Nb_Cols = My_Table.Columns.Count
Nb_Rows = My_Table.rows.count

For I = 1 to Nb_Rows
    For J = 1 to Nb_Cols
        My_Array(I,J) = My_Table.Cell(I,J).Range.Text
    Next J
Next I
```

None of the other methods I have tested has improved the code performance, some of them has made it worse! For instance :
- define a range for My_Table, and browse cells of this range.
- convert table to text and then browse paragraphs (convert to text takes ages!)

Any clue to get close to what I would dream of, like in Excel:

My_array = My_table ???

Thanks for any clue to solve that stuff.

P.S. : of course I have considered storing my big table in an Excel spreadsheet, but this implies creating the dynamic link to Excel in my set of programs, which has other drawbacks.

Very best regards.
S.C. (63200 RIOM - France)

Comment: could you explain what is reason behind you want to copy your table into array? what is going next? I believe next step could produce some interesting idea(s) for you...

Comment: as a separate comment... I can imagine that the following scenario could be quite efficient but I didn't test it: **1)** open excel application behind scenes **2)** copy table to excel range **3)** produce array from excel range **4)** close excel

Comment: Personally I would certainly look at KazimierzJawor's suggestion. If that's not an option, if it's a recent version of Windows Word (probably Word 2007 or later) I would consider grabbing the XML of the table's range and using MSXML to extract what you want. *But* to make the XML processing reasonably easy, before that you would probably need to (a) remove any change tracking stuff, (b) remove formatting and (c) unlink all field codes. Might be possible in situ if you know you can discard the changes to the document. Otherwise, you might need to copy to another document first.